# oracle CATSEARCH pass parameters to structured_query for joins

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

someone knows if is there a way to pass parameters to CATSEARCH in structure_query.

For example:

```
create table parent (id, name, otherParentColumns);

create table children (id, parentId, name); 

ctx_ddl.create_index_set('children_set');

ctx_ddl.add_index('children_set','parentId');

create index children_name on children (name) indextype is ctxsys.ctcat parameters ('INDEX SET children_set');
```

[I´m looking for something similar to:]

```
SELECT * from parent p inner join children c on p.id=c.parentId
  WHERE p.otherParentColumns=xxxx and CATSEARCH(c.name, 'aa|bb|cc', 'parentId='||c.parentId) >0;
```

This query is not valid (`ORA-20000: oracle text error, DRG:10849: catsearch does not support functional invocation`)

Is it possible to query to pass the value to only query for the specific children that match the join?

Thank you.